# How to resolve "Access to host class is not allowed or does not exist" in Karate

Tags: karate, java-interop

A bit frustrated that can't make this work, as it is simply documented on this link https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java

Tried to create from scratch using maven archetype and the standalone jar just to make sure its not about folder structure. Please see below screenshots:

[image: Maven Archetype]
[image: Standalone Jar]

Update:
It works after removing .java in the parameter value.

instead of `* def helper = Java.type('examples.users.Helper.java')`
changed it to `* def helper = Java.type('examples.users.Helper')`

But only works when run as cucumber feature from eclipse.
Still cant make it work in vscode.

[image]

Comment: Also created a chat room for anyone who also use this testing framework by Peter. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/243557/karate-testing

Comment: sorry, screenshots don't help at all: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - my only advice is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Just to give an update @PeterThomas. I've created an issue on karate-runner github.
https://github.com/kirksl/karate-runner/issues/138. Waiting for Kirk response.

Comment: these are open-source projects. using java in a non-maven project may need some extra settings. we urge you to also investigate and contribute your findings back to the community

Answer (score 1):

It works after removing .java in the parameter value.

```
instead of 
* def helper = Java.type('examples.users.Helper.java') 

changed it to 
* def helper = Java.type('examples.users.Helper')
```